# Django is not taking GET input in AJAX call

Tags: python, jquery, django

I am trying to take username input and return in ajax call whether the username is taken or not in Django. But the method in DJango is not taking the input. I am sharing the code here.

URL.py

```
url(r'^search_username/$', user.views.search_product, name="search_username"),
```

script + HTML

```
{% load staticfiles %}


  {% block content %}
  <form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input name="search" id="search" type="text"/>
  <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
    </form>
  {% endblock %}
```

```
$("#search").change(function () {

  var username = $(this).val();

  $.ajax({
    url: '/search_username/',
    data: {
      'username': username
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(){
        alert('failure');
    },
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.is_taken) {
        alert("A user with this username already exists.");
      }
    }
  });

});
```

Views.py

```
def search_username(request):
    print('Entered into search')
    username = request.GET.get('search', None)
    print(username)
    data = {
       'is_taken': allproductlist.objects.filter(product_name_english__iexact=username).exists()
    }

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

The problem is it prints Entered into search.But when I print username it shows NOne. Can anyone please specify what is happening ?

Comment: Totally unrelated but your form should use the GET method - POST is when you want to change the server's state which is not the case here.

Comment: Yes I have also changed it. And also done other custom systems.Working fine alhamdulillah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Ajax is sending the data as "username" but your Python is looking for "search".

Comment: Sir you are a beauty.  I am a very newbie in ajax and js. Thanks . Fixed my problem for a while.

Answer (score 2):

you are sending `username` in ajax request but you are getting `search` in views.py.

you can Update your ajax code:

```
$("#search").change(function () {

  var username = $(this).val();

  $.ajax({
    url: '/search_username/',
    data: {
      'search': username
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(){
        alert('failure');
    },
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.is_taken) {
        alert("A user with this username already exists.");
      }
    }
  });

});
```

2nd way is that you can change in views.py.

```
username = request.GET.get('username', None)
```